# How do I correctly pull from a List<GameObjects> in a parent object's script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a parent object (Flock) with a public List of child objects (Boids). I need each Boid to be able to check that list every Update() for nearby neighbours so I can implement some flocking behaviour.

```
public List<GameObject> neighbours = new List<GameObject>();

void updateNeighbours()
{
    neighbours.Clear();
    neighboursCentre = Vector3.zero;

    foreach (GameObject otherBoid in GetComponentInParent<Flock>().boids)
    {
        if (otherBoid != this && Vector3.Distance(otherBoid.transform.position, this.transform.position) < flockingRadius)
        {
            neighbours.Add(otherBoid);
            neighboursCentre += otherBoid.transform.position;
        }
    }

    //Draw line to centre of neighbours
    neighboursCentre = new Vector3(neighboursCentre.x / (float)neighbours.Count, 0.5f, neighboursCentre.z / (float)neighbours.Count);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, neighboursCentre, Color.green);
}
```

By making the neighbours List public I can see that each Boid's list of neighbours falls in to one of two categories:

- If the Boid is within flockingDistance of the global origin, neighbours is a copy of the entire list from the parent Flock, containing every Boid (including itself)
- If the Boid is further from the global origin than flockingDistance, neighbours is empty.

The DrawLine() calls are resulting in just a spider of rays from the origin to all Boids that are within flockingRadius of it.

So it's definitely referencing the parent object's List correctly, but I'm doing something very wrong in the if() statement. I'm expecting the code to result in each Boid having a subset of its nearby siblings in the neighbours List, but it just seems to result in all-or-nothing. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Instantiation is by the Flock script attached to parent Flock object:

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i=0; i<flockSize; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(boid);
        boid.name = ("Boid" + i);
        boids.Add(boid);
    }
}
```

Hierarchy is set within Boid script in Start():

```
    transform.SetParent(FindObjectOfType<Flock>().transform);
```

Comment: Please include the full object hierarchy of the flock including showing what gets highlighted when you click on an element of `neighbors`. Also show which GameObjects have the script shown in the question attached, if those are different GameObjects.

Comment: Image added, showing runtime hierarchy and highlighted element of neighbours List. The script is attached to the Boid prefab.

Looks like neighbours is being populated by... the prefab, and not the GameObjects in the parent object's list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't a `GameObject`, so you should use `otherBoid != this.gameObject` instead:

```
if (otherBoid != this.gameObject 
    && Vector3.Distance(
            otherBoid.transform.position, 
            this.transform.position) < flockingRadius)
```

You also need to change how you are populating the `boids` list so that you are adding the instantiated `GameObject`, not references to the prefab:

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i=0; i<flockSize; i++)
    {
        GameObject newBoid = Instantiate(boid);
        newBoid.name = ("Boid" + i);
        boids.Add(newBoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much - you've saved me from despair. I was so focussed on the Boid script I didn't think to check the original list :)